# Fast command to calculate the mean of a column in a text file in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

Given a tab separated data file (or another separator), how would you compute the mean of a column?

Too bad that there are no simple binaries that performs simple mathematical operations over those kind of files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum / NR }'
```

Here `$1` is the first `\t`ab-separated column.

Answer (score 3):

If you have R installed you can also use:

```
Rscript -e "(mean(read.table(\"file.tab\")))"
```

You can also change the function (mean) to other statistical functions, say:

```
Rscript -e "(mean(read.table(\"file.tab\")))"
Rscript -e "(sd(read.table(\"file.tab\")))"
Rscript -e "(summary(read.table(\"file.tab\")))"
```

If you want to specify the column, say, use column 3, then you use the notation [,3]

```
Rscript -e "(sum(read.table(\"file\")[,3]))"
```

Enjoy!